# How can I find the NPM package that is blocking a nested dependency from updating?

Tags: npm, npm-audit, npm-vulnerabilities

When I run

```bash
npm audit
```

It tells me I have a critical vulnerability in `lodash`. When I run

```bash
npm ls lodash
```

I have **47** instances of `lodash` being deduped.

How can I tell which of my dependencies are holding on to the vulnerable version?

Answer (score 0):

If you *temporarily* add the vulnerable package at the patched version:

```json
"lodash": ">=4.17.21",
```

to your `package.json` and then run `npm update <VULNERABLE_PACKAGE>` for the vulnerable package. NPM will update all the child dependencies it can.

You can then run `npm outdated --depth=5 <VULNERABLE_PACKAGE>` and it will show which dependencies are forcing an earlier version.

Comment: I hope this helps someone, it took me much too long to figure out.